# Django app dissapears from Django Admin site when I add apps.py file

Tags: python, django

I'm working with Django 3.2 and trying to configure correctly the `AppsConfig` subclass of `apps.py` in order to avoid duplicate apps names when initzialing the project.

The context is the following. I have in my `INSTALLED_APPS` two apps whose names are equal although their paths not:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'first_app.myapp',
    'second_app.myapp'
]
```

To avoid the error shown below (and according to the documentation), I need to create an `apps.py` file subclassing `AppConfig` in at least one of the apps called `myapp`. I've decided to create that file in the second one, `second_app.myapp`.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: myapp
```

The `app.py` in `second_app.myapp` module looks like as follows:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MySecondAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "second_app.myapp"
    label = "my_second_app"
```

And in the `__init__.py` I've added:

```py
default_app_config = 'second_app.myapp.apps.MySecondAppConfig'
```

My `admin.py` looks like:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel


class MySecondAppAdminModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('attr_1', 'attr_2')


admin.site.register(MyModel, MySecondAppAdminModel)
```

When I start the project all works OK and I can use that model information, views called from `second_app.myapp` also work OK.
The problem comes when I access to the admin site (`http://localhost:8000/admin`), where only appears the `first_app.myapp` admin form instead of both.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'first_app.myapp',
    'second_app.myapp'
]
```

Just try this way only:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'first_app',
    'second_app'
]
```

You got that error because here `first_app.myapp` and `second_app.myapp` myapp is duplicate. you should not use like this in both the apps.

**OR**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        ...
        'first_app.apps.MyFirstAppConfig',
        'second_app.apps.MySecondAppConfig'
    ]
```